# How to update audio input range slider with values from React Context

Tags: reactjs, html5-audio, react-context

I need help with updating the range input slider. I have a music context file where i have the logic for playing music when the play button is clicked. Everything works but the audio slider does not move as the music is playing. it only jumps to the value of the current time of the audio when i click on the pause button. The logic for play and pause is in the playmusic method of the musiccontext file. Does anyone know what i can do to fix this? I think i need a better way to handle the onchange method of the audio input.[[image]](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
[image]

[image]

I tried updating the value with state directly in the AudioController.js component and used useEffect to update the state with settimeout. It worked but i need to use the music context play and pause method.

Comment: Please don't upload code as images since this makes it really hard for anyone to reproduce, see the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how to do this